# Cells Do Not Appear in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having an issue with displaying cells in my `UITableViewController`, simply..nothing shows up when I go to test. Below is my code.

**FormationViewController.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FormationViewController.h"

@interface FormationViewController ()

@end

@implementation FormationViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.names count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Title"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Title"];
    }

    NSString *name = _names[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
    return cell;
}

- (void)        tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Formation View";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_icon_formation"];
        self.names = @[@"John Doe", @"Lee Harvey Oswald", @"Pat Buchanan", @"Angry Orchard",
                       @"Sierra Nevad", @"Jeff Bridges", @"John McClain", @"Lucy Genero"];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"The length of names is %lu", self.names.count);
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.formationVC.frame = CGRectMake(
                                        0,
                                        self.topLayoutGuide.length,
                                        CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),
                                        CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)
                                        - self.topLayoutGuide.length
                                        - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
                                        );
}

- (void)loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.formationVC = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.formationVC.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [view addSubview:self.formationVC];

    self.view = view;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
@end
```

And my **FormationViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FormationViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *formationVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *names;

@end
```

I'm also not sure if I'm putting some of these lines of code in the right methods.

I also think that my problem might be lying in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I'm not absolutely sure I'm implementing that 100% correctly.

If anyone can help me find out what I'm doing wrong please let me know. This is my first Obj-C/iOS project I'm working on too so please be gentle! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try to print out the value before 
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
just to make sure it is not empty first.

Comment: I guess your names array is empty. Did you check its size and what is the output of the NSLog statement in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Is your self.table properly connected to the table in your nib?

Comment: Is initWithNibName ever called at all? Try NSLogging something there. What I do is that I write my own initData method which I simply call from each init... method that may be called by the framework.

Comment: Can you able to show atleast empty cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried your code , using no xibs and faced the same problem.
Then I changed 2 things

removed LoadView. 
moved  self.names intialization from initWithNibName to viewDidLoad

added

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Title"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to viewDidload 
And it worked

Comment: So being new to Obj-C what did those two lines I needed to add do for me? What class are these methods under or inherit from?

Comment: Since I didn't use xib or storyboard, the registerClass method was needed for setting what kind of TableViewCell class will be used with what kind of identifier. reloadData was to reload the tableView. Since initWithNibName wasn't getting called, I moved the initialisation of self.name array to viewDidLoad , so that once the view gets loaded, the array will be intialised, as well as the tableview will be registered for the TableView class

Answer (score 0):

I think you' re never stop in `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` ... if you instantiate your view controller from a storyboard, you need to implement `initWithCoder`, or just put your names initialization in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably using Storyboard, check these steps:

1) Storyboard - select your table view controller and in Identity Inspector make sure you have it's class set to your FormationVC.

2) Storyboard - select table view inside the controller and select it's first cell (suggesting you use Prototype Cells). Make sure it's style is set to Basic and set it's identifier for example to "BasicCell".

3) Go to your code and use this:

**FormationVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FormationVC : UITableViewController
@end
```

**FormationVC.m**

```
#import "FormationVC.h"
@interface FormationVC ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *names;
@end

@implementation FormationVC

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // you must not forget to call your custom init method once the view is loaded
    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView {

    // set title of VC
    self.title = @"Formation View";

    // create array of names
    _names = @[@"John Doe", @"Lee Harvey Oswald", @"Pat Buchanan", @"Angry Orchard",
               @"Sierra Nevad", @"Jeff Bridges", @"John McClain", @"Lucy Genero"];

    // log number of names in names array
    NSLog(@"The length of names is %lu", _names.count);

}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_names count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BasicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _names[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem IS there :-

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *names;
```

change `NSArray`To `NSMutableArray`

```
in.h
```

EX:- `@property (nonatomic , retain) NSMutableArray *names`

and `in.m`

```
names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and then alloc init your Array and then put value its work .

Comment: That is not his problem. Not at this stage. The array is created once as NSArray using @[...], is assigned exactly once and never ever changed. And if he tried doing so then he would have got an exception anyway.

Comment: Regarding you edit: it is not required to alloc and init an array, especially when the property gets assigned a different array later. That would be just a waste of time and memory.

Comment: NSString *name = _names[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
    return cell;


you can put this 

cell.textLabel.text = [_names objectAtTheIndex indexPath.row];